# Skype video upside down LD_PRELOAD

Tags: skype

I got this error when I tried to load Skype with `v4lcompat.so` to solve my upside down problem.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' exist? If it doesn't try to look for it with `locate v4l1compat`.